# schema mongoose unexpected identifier

Tags: javascript, node.js

When i run this code with nodejs, it returns me this error: **"SyntaxError: Unexpected Identifier"** in this line...

> var user_schema = New Schema({
>
> ```
>                        ^^^^^^^
> ```

i do not know what is the problem... (sorry for my english, i speak spanish)

```
---------------- APP.JS CODE ------------------

var http = require("http");
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
var jade = require("jade");
var mongodb = require("mongodb");
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var user = require("./public/js/users").user;
var bodyparser = require("body-parser");

app.set('view engine', 'jade');
mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost/SoR");
app.use(express.static("public"));
app.use("/public",express.static("public"));
app.use(bodyparser.json());
//app.use(bodyparser.urlEncoded({extended: true}));

app.get("/login",function(req,res){
    res.render("login");
});

app.get("/",function(req,res){
    res.render("index");
});

app.get("/signup",function(req,res){
    res.render("signup");
});

app.post("/users",function(req,res){
    var user = new user({email: req.body.email, username: req.body.username, password: req.body.password});
    user.save(function(){
        console.log(req.body.email);
        console.log(req.body.password);
        console.log(req.body.id);
        res.send("save succesfull");
    });
});

app.listen(8080);



---------------USERS.JS CODE -----------

var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var user_schema = New Schema({
    email: String,
    username: String,
    password: String
});

var user = mongoose.model("user","user_schema");
mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost/SoR");
module.exports.user = user;
```

Comment: try `new` instead of `New`

Answer (score 5):

Change the `New` to `new`. `new` is the Keyword to create a object using the constructor function in javascript.

Javascript doesn't recognize the `New`operator that you used in the code and hence you get the error  "SyntaxError: Unexpected Identifier" as `New` is an unexpected identifier.

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/SyntaxError)

> A SyntaxError is thrown when the JavaScript engine encounters tokens
>   or token order that does not conform to the syntax of the language
>   when parsing code.

```
var user_schema = New Schema({
    email: String,
    username: String,
    password: String
});
```

to

```
var user_schema = new Schema({
    email: String,
    username: String,
    password: String
});
```